# FragmentTabHost tabs to be refreshed on Custom callback method?

Tags: android, fragment, android-fragmentactivity, fragment-tab-host

I have FragmentTabHost in my fragment activity and I have a Custom callback method on which I want to refresh my current selected tab and its fragment... How can I do that? Also its possible that the application is in background when the callback happened, in that case I want to ignore it.

Here's what I have tried doing :

```
            public void OnCustomCallback(){
                  runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                      @Override
                      public void run() {
                         if (mTabHost != null) {
                            mTabHost.invalidate();
                      }
                  }
               });
             }
```

Comment: Where are refreshing it?

Comment: I didnt get what you are asking.. Are you asking why i am refreshing it. then its a login fragment and on click i need to refresh login button to logout button.

Comment: I mean when is onCustomcallback is called

Comment: Its called when every interval I download details from our webservice. Rite now interval is say 30 mins. so every 30 mins this method gets called and the fragment needs to be refreshed.

Comment: Does invalidate work?

Comment: No it doesnt work at all :(

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/59143/discussion-between-kruti-mevada-and-rod-algonquin).

Comment: Did you find solution? mTabHost.invalidate() doing nothing on view.